# Upgrade from ejabberd 2.1.9 to latest (22.10)

Tags: ejabberd

tried to serach in documentation but I have a lot of doubts...

I'm running ejabberd version 2.1.9 on an old debian server (5.0.8) with more than 500 users...

Now I was asked to update to the latest version, but I need some advice;
in the documentation I saw there are specific upgrade instructions between versions also from 2.1.x to 16.02
if I upgrade to 16 version can I jump directly to 22.10 or I have to upgrade to every intermediate releases?

or as an alternative, is possible to export users, passowrds, shared rooster ecc..and restore them on a fresh installed 22.10 ?

@badlop

Thank you very much for detailed info :-)
but I'm stuck with backup database... If I use the plain text backup "ejabberdctl dump" give me errors importing table "pubsub_node" on the new server

```
** Table pubsub_node already exists on ejabberd@localhost, just entering data
Problem 'error {case_clause,
                {aborted,
                 {bad_type,
                  {pubsub_item,
                   {"751ca223b3f58d185f3afef05d0e3d4eb236c376",218},
                   {{1317,45407,740776},{"donkeykong","acme.com",[]}},
                   {{1317,133197,815914},
                    {"donkeykong","acme.com","stc"}},
                   [{xmlelement,"metadata",
                     [{"xmlns","urn:xmpp:avatar:metadata"}],
                     [{xmlelement,"info",
                       [{"id","751ca223b3f58d185f3afef05d0e3d4eb236c376"},
                        {"type","image/png"},
                        {"bytes","16541"},
                        {"width","96"},
                        {"height","94"}],
                       []}]}]}}}}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_admin,load_mnesia,1},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5}]
```

tried editing and removing the pubsub_item, but the problem will show on the next pubsub_item.

If I try to use "ejabberdctl backup" the server reply with this error

```
Can't store backup in "/tmp/jabba.backup" at node ejabberd@jabba: {"Cannot prepare checkpoint (replica not available)",
                                                                   [temporarily_blocked,
                                                                    {{1670,
                                                                      255465,
                                                                      408029},
                                                                     ejabberd@jabba}]}
```

even if I have only one node

The import error of dump came up even if I try to make a little jump from 2.1.9 to 2.1.13

any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> with more than 500 users

An ejabberd server with around 500 online users? That's a small server, I guess you don't even use SQL database, so that's one less thing to worry about.

An ejabberd deployment is composed of:

- the code (source or binary)
- configuration file (or files)
- mnesia internal database, that is stored in the mnesia spool dir (see [system install](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#system-install))
- SQL database (if you configure it)
- log files (only useful for your interest and consult)

When upgrading ejabberd code, it is usual that the release notes mention some changes in the configuration, and some changes in SQL schemas. The changes in the mnesia internal database are implemented inside ejabberd and applied automatically when needed.

> I have to upgrade to every intermediate releases?

In general no need. In general when jumping a few releases, you just read the release notes and apply the configuration and SQL schema changes of all the intermediate releases.

But in your case... as it's a big jump, I recommend you to not touch the production server yet. First test the upgrade in another machine (your personal machine, or other unused server, or a laptop, or a docker container...), so you learn how to do it perfectly without annoying the users.

There are many ways; but I were you, or if I were sitting in a chair next to you, this is how I would do it. I would be optimistic and try to jump from from 2.1.9 to 22.10, but slowly, and using a temporary server for testing the process and learning:

1. In a testing machine install the desired ejabberd version (22.10 or whatever). It should work perfectly, as it's empty and has default configuration. Notice most XMPP clients allow you to login to an account whatever@example.com specifying the IP address and port of the server: in your case you will have to specify the IP address of the new ejabberd server, as the XMPP domain it doesn't match the DNS name.
2. Obviously, the configuration in the new server will lack customizations that are essential for you (the served domain, what accounts are admins, certificate files, port numbers, custom modules...)
3. Copy the old configuration file to the new server. Notice they use different formats (ejabberd.cfg in erlang format... and ejabberd.yml in YAML format).
4. Manually and slowly apply one of your customizations in the new configuration file. Restart ejabberd, check it starts and works correctly, and then repeat with another customization.
5. Now you have a new ejabberd server running, with all (or most) of your desired configuration. Two things are lacking: the users data, and of course replacing the old ejabberd with the new ejabberd.
6. In the production ejabberd server, export the mnesia database using "[ejabberdctl backup](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#backup)" and "[ejabberdctl dump](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#dump)" (better to have two alternatives, in case one doesn't work). Copy those files to the machine that has the new ejabberd server.
7. In the new ejabberd, run [restore](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#restore) specifying the binary backup
   (or [load](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#load) specifying the text dump). With some luck, this will end correctly.
8. Restart ejabberd. It will notice that the mnesia tables use very old schemas, and will automatically update them. This may take a while. With some luck it will end correctly.
9. If steps 7 or 8 fail, and you are lucky to know what username or what data is problematic, you can try to delete or "fix" that in the text dump file before loading it).
10. Once you are happy with the new ejabberd server (the new configuration looks great, has all your customizations, and all the users are correctly imported), then it's time to replace the old ejabberd with the new one.

Alternatively, you can try to upgrade from 2.1.9 to 16.02, and later from 16.02 to 22.10

In any case, general recommendations:

- take it slowly because there are many steps
- be patient because you may face small problems that require fixing before continuing to the next step
- be kind to yourself because you never did this
- annotate every major problem you face, and how you fixed it (in case you find this problem again this day or in the next days, or eventually somebody else in your organization)
- be sure this can be done (in the worst case, with a progressive upgrade from one version to the next :)